# How to properly install program to /opt dir

Tags: debian, installation, hfs

I've installed program `qcad` to `/opt/qcad-dir` directory. Binaries are in `/opt/qcad-dir` at all in one place. I had to change native `qcad.sh` script to use program as alternative (`update-alternatives`). I added `DIR=/opt/qcad-dir` to run the program with its libs, otherwise, qcad that run from another directory isn't saw its' libs.

So. I moved all program files into `/opt/qcad-dir`, then I change `qcad.sh` to make it possible to run from another directory. I created symlink to alternative. And now it is available to run `qcad` from anywhere.

Is it more correct way to install program (which stores all binaries in the same dir) system widely?

Answer (score 1):

The [Linux Standard Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base) and the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) are arguably the standards of where and how you should install software on a Linux system and would suggest placing software that isn't included in your distribution either in `/opt` or `/usr/local/` or rather subdirectories therein `(/opt/<package>  /opt/<provider>  /usr/local/bin).`

Best practice is to convert software you download to a installable software package native to your distribution, for instance dpkg or rpm formats. That will facilitate reporting, upgrading and cleanly removing the software.

Comment: If there is no building scripts, should I do the package for program by myself?

Comment: In addition, to precise my question. In whole story I didn't like the way I changed run script. This is dirty way, I think, to modify maintainer-supplied stuff.